# Change Application font size at runtime

Tags: wpf, mvvm, styles, mvvm-light, font-size

I have a project with multiply subsystem. and created a project for every subsystem.

I use MVVMLight in this project.

I set a resource for main project and set font-size for it.

I want change ui font-size at runtime.

When i use this code, it change font size only mainwindows, but i want to change font size for all child windows.

```
Application.Current.MainWindow.FontSize = 12;
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of setting a new fontsize i use ScaleTransform in my project maybe its also a way for you

```
<Window>
 <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <Border Grid.Row="0">
        <Border.LayoutTransform>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding ElementName=zoomer, Path=Value}" ScaleY="{Binding ElementName=zoomer, Path=Value}"></ScaleTransform>
        </Border.LayoutTransform>
        <!-- content here -->
    </Border>
    <Slider Grid.Row="1" x:Name="zoomer" Width="100" Focusable="False" Value="1" 
            Minimum="1" Maximum="2.2" TickFrequency="0.1" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True"/>
   </Grid>
  </Window>
```

Comment: Thanks , but i have multiply project that use in application, and i want to change font size all project with a button in a special project.

Comment: then save the "new" fontsize in application settings and bind to it

Answer (score 0):

While the `FontSize` property is inherited by child controls, it can be tricky to set it on a `Window` and have all child controls inherit that value. If any child control has explicitly set their own `FontSize` property value, then that will 'override' any that is set on a parent.

I don't know any way to set the `FontSize` of *all* `Window`s in an application, but you *can* set the `FontSize` of all of the *open* `Window`s in an application at run time:

```
foreach (Window window in Application.Current.Windows) window.FontSize = 12;
```

Furthermore, if you want to set a property just on the open `Window`s of a particular type, then you can do this:

```
foreach (Window window in Application.Current.Windows.OfType<DialogWindow>()) 
    window.FontSize = 12;
```

Comment: Yes , i can set font-size for open windows, but Is there any solution for set font-size for ui that when open new windows, set font-size for it.

Comment: What method do you use to open a new `Window`?

Comment: I use `window.Show();`

Comment: Then why don't you just call `window.FontSize = 12;` first?

Comment: thanks, but i set font size in another project, and open window is another, i don't save font size.